# Using tsUnit with NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript

So I found [tsUnit](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit) library that I am trying to figure out how to use in a nodeJS project.  I did find that the example projects on the tsUnit page have .html files but I'm hoping that I could just run the unit test.

```
import tsUnit = require('../tsUnit'); 
module CalcTest {
    class TryATest extends tsUnit.TestClass {
        test() {
            this.areIdentical(4,4);
        }
    }
}      
var test = new tsUnit.Test(CalcTest);

var result  = test.run();
```

The result I get is:

```
var previousHandler = window.onhashchange;    
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at TestRunLimiter.setRefreshOnLinksWithHash
at new TestRunLimiter
at new Test
at Object.<anonymous>
at Module._compile
at Object.Module._extensions..js
at Module.load
at Function.Module._load
at Function.Module.runMain
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve fenton just fixed it : https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit/commit/e8676f23b0b37c072e34c4caa01f1301ed1eb1fd removing dependency on `window` for running in nodejs.

Get the latest version.